# Does this specific diagram transformation (and the algebra that has this property) have a name in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to learn and apply category theory to analyze a program I'm developing.  In the system I'm studying, I realized that every span `A <- Y -> B` can be "rotated" or "reflected" by introducing a new node `A;B` with three arrows such that `A -> A;B` and `B <- A;B -> Y`.

I say rotation because if you arranged A,Y,B in a triangle with Y at the peak, the span starts out oriented like `/\` and finishes oriented like `/_` (provided you draw node `A;B` on top of node `A`).  Alternatively if you draw the new node below the triangle, the diagram looks like a pool reflecting a roof line.

Metaphors aside, this is not a frivolous exercise in drawing pretty pictures with objects and arrows.  In the program I'm studying, the transformation has a (computable!) semantic meaning: 
 "Anywhere I see the product Y := A AND B, I may introduce a plan to evaluate *first A;then B*, so that by following A to A;B I obtain B and Y."

What I'm wondering is, is this diagram transformation something that has a name already in category theory?  The closest thing I could find in my readings so far is the "comma object", but the two are not graph isomorphic (not even if you relabel nodes and not even if you take the dual of one of them).

**Edit:**  Interestingly, once one assumes a rule that a span can be bridged via an arrow into a fresh node that roots a rotation of the span, it's not actually necessary for the retrograde arrow in the rule definition to still point opposite from the others! (To wit: the arrow `A -> A;B` in the rule substitution can instead be `A <- A;B` so that it's not in any way 'special'.)  This makes `A;B` simply the triple product of `A, B, Y`.  Instead of explicitly including an arrow closing spans, we can close any two legs of the result of the substitution by recursively invoking the rule again, for example to close the span `A <- A;B -> Y`. Of course, that just creates a new node `A;;A;B;;Y` and more spans...  However if we consider this to be a case of Zeno's paradox then we may declare that an infinite regression of such substitutions amounts to the same thing as being able to reach the destination.

**Edit 2:**  I think this Product(A,B) => A-then-B business corresponds to pattern matching / rewriting systems or grammars.  Recast into the terms I presented the question under, you could imagine each node carries additional, unstated (and polymorphic) state, and "function" calls transform only the mentioned state but all the unmentioned state (i.e. the environment) comes along too.  Perhaps the answer is that this just isn't a Category.  (?)

This seems promising:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_rewriting

Comment: Well, if execution of $A;B$ stops after executing $A$, we *won't get* $A;B\to B$ and $A;B\to Y$. By the way, in general, an arrow like $A;B\to Y$ could not arise simply from a span $A\leftarrow Y\to B$..

Comment: Correct it's not something that would arise in general, but that could just mean this is a special property of this particular system.  I'm not sure what you mean by stops executing?  Perhaps I better define the arrow A -> A;B to mean "execute a function f : A -> B", then you cannot have gotten to node A;B if the function did not execute:  if that were the case then you have not followed arrow.  So node A;B is only reachable if we have successfully executed the function, and from that it follows that product Y and operand B do have arrows from A;B.